# C++ template self name passing as a template template parameter inside of same template structure function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I cant use template name inside of same template.I want to use it like below.But it gives me error.Here is the code;

```
   template <unsigned int N, template <class...> class ClassName, class ... InsideClass> struct GetNthTypeOfNested;
    template<unsigned int N, template<class...> class ClassName, class FirstOfInsideClass, class ... RestOfInsideClass>
    struct GetNthTypeOfNested<N, ClassName, FirstOfInsideClass, RestOfInsideClass...>:GetNthTypeOfNested<N - 1, ClassName, RestOfInsideClass...>{};
    template<template<class...> class ClassName, class ... InsideClass>
    struct GetNthTypeOfNested<0, ClassName, InsideClass...>{
        typedef typename ClassName<InsideClass...> type;
    };

    template<typename ... Args> struct Typer;
    template<>
    struct Typer<>{

    };
    template<typename First,typename ... Args>
    struct Typer<First,Args...>:Typer<Args...>{
        template<unsigned int N>
        void get(){
            cout << typeid(typename GetNthTypeOfNested<N, Typer, First, Args...>::type).name();
//Typer undefined here i cant use Typer but i can use Typer outside of function
        }
    };
```

Comment: Post an example that clearly shows the error you are seeing (including instantiations), along with the error itself. The only error I get with the above code is for `typedef typename ClassName<InsideClass...> type;` which doesn't need `typename`.

Comment: if i call function like that it gives me a bunch of errors . Typer<int, float, double> f;
 f.get<1>();
this is the important error,
error C3200: 'Typer<int,float,double>' : invalid template argument for template parameter 'ClassName', expected a class template

Comment: As I mentioned above you'll need to remove the `typename`, you'll still get an error from `get` though because you have ambitious template instantiations.

Comment: `typeid(typename GetNthTypeOfNested<N, Typer, First, Args...>::type` -> replace `Typer` with `::Typer`.

Comment: thanks Constructor it works now but why i need to access it from global ? why i cant use simply Typer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Previous version was incorrect because of a misreading)

You have an ambiguous template instantiation.

Change your `GetNthTypeOfNested<0,...>` specialization to

```
template<template<class...> class ClassName, 
         class FirstOfInsideClass,                              // <- change here
         class ... InsideClass>
struct GetNthTypeOfNested<0, 
                          ClassName, 
                          FirstOfInsideClass,                   // <- and here
                          InsideClass...>
{
    typedef ClassName<FirstOfInsideClass, InsideClass...> type; // <- and here
};
```

Also replace replace `Typer` with `::Typer` inside `Typer` because of a VC++ bug.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c9c795013626a63).

There are two things in this example that are handled differently by different compilers.

1. VC++ does not recognize the template specialization as ambiguous. Both gcc and clang do. This is probably a VC++ bug.
2. VC++ does not recognize `Typer` with no template parameters as a template. gcc does, clang does not. It looks like a bug in both VC++ and clang. (Update: this is indeed [clang bug #9551](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9551)).

Says 14.6.1/1:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9). The injected class-name can be used as a template-name or a type-name. When it is used with a template-argument-list, **as a template-argument for a template template-parameter**, or as the final identifier in the elaborated-type-specifier of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the class template itself.

Comment: nope it s working if u check it u ll see yourself.Constructor answer is correct one.

Comment: Well his version [does not work for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/812dc0df5176863a), but what do I know.